# MySQL Count + Grouping for a Field value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
Date       | Code

2012-04-01 | 1
2012-04-01 | 0
2012-04-01 | 0
2012-04-01 | 2
2012-04-02 | 4
2012-04-03 | 1
2012-04-03 | 0
2012-04-03 | 0
2012-04-04 | 1
2012-04-04 | 3
2012-04-04 | 4
2012-04-04 | 4
2012-04-04 | 0
```

Code is predefined from 0-5.

What I would like is a query that Counts by the Code & Date, where each Record is for 1 Date.
Each predefined code should be counted in a separate field.

So, the Result should be like:

```
Date       | Code0 | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 | Code5

2012-04-01 |     2 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 
2012-04-02 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     1 |     0 
2012-04-03 |     2 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |     0 
2012-04-04 |     1 |     1 |     0 |     3 |     4 |     0
```

I would like to do this in the most efficient way possible, the data size would be around 400,000, so some union based queries may hurt the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `Date`,
  SUM(IF(`Code`=0,1,0)) AS `Code0`,
  SUM(IF(`Code`=1,1,0)) AS `Code1`,
  SUM(IF(`Code`=2,1,0)) AS `Code2`,
  SUM(IF(`Code`=3,1,0)) AS `Code3`,
  SUM(IF(`Code`=4,1,0)) AS `Code4`
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY `Date`
```

This will traverse your table only once, which is as good as it gets.

Comment: However, I would like to add that I was looking for the occurrence of the data rather the sum of it, so COUNT instead of SUM in my case.

Comment: @Araejay: The `SUM()` of either 1 or 0 is the same thing as the count of the matching rows. `COUNT()` doesn't allow filters, so I chose `SUM(IF())` as a conditional count.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
select `date`, 
       sum(code=0) as code0, 
       sum(code=1) as code1,
       sum(code=2) as code2,
       sum(code=3) as code3, 
       sum(code=4) as code4, 
       sum(code=5) as code5           
from your_table
group by `date`
```